# jquery page loading delay

Tags: jquery, load, external

I want to load a div from external source after page has loaded with some delay.

Here is the jquery script I have. What is happening is content is loading first and then loader.gif later. How can I show content from an external source after some xx time..? I have an idea about `.load()` function but not sure how to implement.

```
$(window).load(function() {
$('<div id="overlay"><img src="loading.gif" /></div>')
.css('opacity', '0.5')
.insertAfter('body');

window.setTimeout(function() {
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#overlay').remove();
});}, 1000);
$('.body').show();
});

<div id="container">
<div id="header">navigation</div>
<div id="body" class="body">Body</div>
<div id="footer">footer</div>
</div>


#overlay {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background: gray;
}

.body{display:none;}

#overlay img {
 display: block;
 width: 32px;
 height: 32px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 margin: -26px 0 0 -26px;
 padding: 10px;
 background: #fff;
 -moz-border-radius: 6px;
 border-radius: 6px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You said that the gif is being loaded after you ajax pull. If that is your problem, you can call your ajax pull after the gif is loaded, by doing:

```
yourimg = new Image(); 
yourimg.src = "loading.gif";

yourimg.loadEvent = function(url, image){
    var overlay = $('<div id="overlay" />');
    overlay.append(image).css('opacity', '0.5').insertAfter('body');
    //call whatever you want here. your image is loaded.
}

yourimg.load();
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [jquery website](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)

```
The load event is sent to an element when it and all sub-elements have been
completely loaded. This event can be sent to any element associated with a URL: 
images scripts, frames, iframes, and the window object.
```

You need to show your div while the body is loading and hide it onload. I'm not sure if that is what you're asking though. If it's not the [setTimeout](http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/) function might be what you want.

Comment: Yes, actually that is not what i am looking here. The content which is loading in the body div will be heavy. So, i want to load the main page first and then body div content using .load() function.

Answer (score 0):

There's a small problem in your code:

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
$(document).ready(function() {
...
```

In this code you set the timeout, to the function that does this:

```
function() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#overlay').remove();
    });
}
```

Basically it waits a second, and then adds a listener to document's ready event and in that listener it performs the actual work. So in case if ready event was fired during the first second - the function will not execute at all.

Your code should look like this:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        // Do the dom manipulations remove the placeholder
    }, 1000);
});
```

The placeholder will be removed in a second after the load event. Note that "load" and "ready" events are different. And "load" doesn't guarantee that DOM will be parsed or rendered.

Comment: @Juiry UPDATE sorry, if i have confused, Actually this what i am looking here. The content which is loading in the body div will be very heavy. So, i want to load the main page first and then body div content using .load() function.